# Can't play mp4 video using html5 video tag

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I am trying to present an mp4 video (h264) using html5:

```
<video width="320" controls>
            <source src="/home/nabil/FWork/hikvision/ch01_00000100068000101.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

analyzing video codec with ffmpeg gives the following:

```
ffprobe ch01_00000100068000101.mp4 
ffprobe version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Invalid UE golomb code
    Last message repeated 3 times
Input #0, mpeg, from 'ch01_00000100068000101.mp4':
  Duration: 00:09:27.33, start: 35024.106667, bitrate: 507 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 90k tbn, 20 tbc
```

a possible relevant detail is that playing the video using ubuntu's default video reader (ffmpeg in the background) doesn't show any video controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is named `.mp4`, but ffmpeg thinks it is actually `.mpg`. It might be right.

Remux:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

But before you do that get a modern ffmpeg. Yours is ancient. For Linux you can either [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure that's the case but the solution you suggestion provided a quick fix without a loss of quality!

Comment: the new ffprobe version gives this error instead (to the old version of the file):[mpeg @ 0x7262cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = NOPTS).